# Error de sintaxis: token inesperado

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código para añadir un nuevo estudiante:

```js
function Student(name, age, classes) {
  Student.name = name;
  Student.age = age;
  Student.classes = classes;
}

Student.proto.addClass = function(class) {
  this[classes].add(class);
};

Student.proto.updateAge = function(age) {
  this[age] = age;
};

var sam = new Student('Sam', 15, ['English', 'Math', 'History', 'Science']);
sam.proto.addClass('Art');
sam.proto.updateAge(16);
```

Me dice error de sintaxis:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token class

¿Cómo hacer para que funcione sin errores?

Comment: Y cuál se supone que es el error que te da?

Comment: Error de sintaxis, lo que quiero saber es en dónde está ese error, gracias!

Comment: @AnaCorin abre la consola de JavaScript de tu navegador y ahí podrás ver en qué línea está el error. Edita la pregunta con esa información.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La palabra **class** es una palabra reservada. Cambiala:

```
Student.proto.addClass = function(clase) {
  this[classes].add(clase);
};
```